# Do Zombicide: Black Plague quests last a lot longer than suggested?

Tags: zombicide, zombicide-black-plague

I bought Zombicide: Black Plague and we played the three first quests (0, 1 and 2). None of us played the other versions.

Now what surprises me. The quests 1 and 2 have an estimated time of 60 minutes. Is it actually possible to complete these that fast ?

For both, we needed more than 2 hours..

**Note:** having no zombicide experience at all doesn't help, for sure, but the difference for these supposed *easy* quests is pretty huge.

Comment: Beware the quests with a 'variable' time. IIRC quest 5 in Wulfsberg has taken 6 hours of gaming, and is still set up on my living room table to be completed! In these cases you might want to set a maximum time limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We too played the first couple of quests in Zombicide: Black Plague and it took us about 2 hours for quests 2 and 3 and we have played previous Zombicide games.
The first quest we played with 2 people (each controlling 2 survivors) and it took us about an hour and a half, but that included a lot of rules checking (there are huge differences in the rules between earlier Zombicide games and Zombicide: Black Plague).

Game designers give these estimates based on play tester feedback. Play testers may have played through a number of different versions of the same map, be more focussed on continuous gameplay than a group of players and have more experience with the rules and various skills.

I would treat the given times as "minimum" and probably add an hour to an hour and a half to these estimates.

The upside to these estimates is that if you want to convince your friends to play one more game before they have to go, you tell them "it'll only take an hour, see here it says so in the quest description."

Comment: The upside can also be a downside when you are not aware that it takes 1-1.5 hours more to complete a quest, like for example when someone has to leave to take the train because well, we didn't finish the quest in the announced time

Comment: Absolutely, but now you know. I was simply looking for the silver lining.